# Delay when checking server status. With jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file, status

I've got a project where i need to check if the server of my application is still online.
After a long search i found a script that worked. But not perfectly. When i unplug the network cable from my server it takes 15 seconds for my application to recognize that the server is down.

The script looks for the file ping.html and for caching reasons i needed to put the random var after it i think :p

Does anyone know how to solve the problem with the delay?

```
function ping(){
           $.ajax({ 
           cache: false,
              url: 'ping.html?myRand=' + guid(), 
              success: function(result){ 
                 $('.conmessage').hide(); 
                 enable();

              },     
              error: function(result){ 
                  $('.conmessage').show();  
                  disable();
              }
           });
        }

    function s4() {
           return (((1+Math.random())*0x10000)|0).toString(16).substring(1);
    }

    function guid() {
           return s4()+s4()+"-"+s4()+"-"+s4()+"-"+s4()+"-"+s4()+s4()+s4();
    }
```

Comment: FYI, you don't need a massively random number in your URL because it only has to be unique on this computer.  In fact, just using a number derived from the current time is more foolproof and a lot simpler.

Comment: agree...time will always be unique as long as you work with UTC time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you should use the timeout property (it's in milliseconds) in your ajax call:

```
$.ajax({ 
              cache: false,
              url: 'ping.html?myRand=' + guid(), 
              timeout: 1000,
              success: function(result){ 
                 $('.conmessage').hide(); 
                 enable();

              },     
              error: function(result){ 
                  $('.conmessage').show();  
                  disable();
              }
           });
```